# advanced php storing and echo'ing mysql data in form of gradebook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Okay, So whats am trying to achieve is a grading book which contains around 10~20 students and the teacher is able to edit them all at the same time, as if its like a real grade book, so I began by designing the table.

[The table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYI4k.png)

and here's the html codes

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:white; text-align:center;!important">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float:left; margin-bottom:20px; "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Assignment</button>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important"><u>Students</u></th>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment:<hr>Due date:<hr>Points:</th>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment 1<hr>1/21/2017<hr>25</th>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment 2<hr>2/21/2017<hr>50</th>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment 3<hr>3/21/2017<hr>75</th>
                <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment 4<hr>4/21/2017<hr>100</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="name">Student/th>
                <td class="a">99% A+</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">24</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">49</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">74</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','4')" onClick="showEdit(this);">99</td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
                <th class="name">Student</th>
                <td class="a">99% A+</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">24</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">49</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">74</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"class="hover allownumericwithoutdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','4')" onClick="showEdit(this);">99</td>
            </tr>
   
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

The html works code and I have that plugin that the grade's boxes will be saved upon edited. but when I began adding the php I want a good way to add the assignments and the grades vertically instead of getting the assignments from the db "assignments" then after listing all the assignments for each student I get the grades blindly from table "grades", I need a way to like for the students it loads the first assignment and the grades for all then saves and with some while or loop functions to get them all. for example,

We get the assignment 1 and load all the students and grades in an array then we go to assignment 2 and do the same but the problem how will be able to list them , please check the html codes and help me on figuring a way to do it.

its like the assignments are added in a row and all the grades are added in another row, I need a way to divide them or IDK.

Let me clarify what I need.

Okay so thats my table php codes so far

```
$check4 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `classes` where teacher_id = ".$u." AND class_id=".$cid."");
                        $rows4 = mysqli_num_rows($check4);
                        if($rows4 != 1)
                        {
                            redirect("index.php");
                        }
                        $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check4);

                        $check5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `assignments` WHERE  `class_id` = ".$row4['class_id']."");
                        $rows5 = mysqli_num_rows($check5);

<?php if($rows5 > 0){echo'
<div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:white; text-align:center;!important">
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#create"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float:left; margin-bottom:20px;    "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Assignment</button></a>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important"><u>Students</u></th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">Assignment:<hr>Due date:<hr>Points:</th>
        ';}?>

            <?php while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check5))
            {
                echo'<th class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;!important">'.$row5["ass_name"].'<hr>'.$row5["ass_due"].'<hr>'.$row5["ass_points"].'</th>';
            }

        if($rows5 > 0){echo'</tr>';} ?>

        <tr>
            <th class="name">Student #0</th>
            <td class="a">99% A+</td>
            <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="hover allownumericwithdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();} if(checkIfEnter(event)){$('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex) + ']').focus();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="name">Student/th>
            <td class="a">Student #1</td>
            <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="hover allownumericwithdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();} if(checkIfEnter(event)){$('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex) + ']').focus();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="name">Student #2</th>
            <td class="a">99% A+</td>
            <td contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="hover allownumericwithdecimal" onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();} if(checkIfEnter(event)){$('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex) + ']').focus();}" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">24</td>
        </tr>

    <?php    
    if($rows5 > 0){echo'    
    </tbody>
    </table>';}?>
```

Okay so that php pastes the table and the assignments would be there, and now I need a mysql and php codes to pull down each student's grades for each assignment I didn't create the database for the grades yet I need to imagine it first. but the problem in my php codes, you first begin by getting the assignments and then getting the grades blindly and that would make lots of conflicts I need a way to get each assignment with every student's grade as a package.

Comment: Tried to clarify it a little more.

Comment: So you are stuck with database table design and database query, right?